# ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = False is not suppressing the alerts and VBA code is not working as expected

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have below VBA code to copy the data from one sheet (Data is derived based on Formulas) to another sheet, but it's not working when I called from informatica tool as it's not able to handle below alert.
[image: 1]

This alert required manual confirmation and working fine when I run and confirm manually.

Code:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("<Source path>")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set objRange = objWorksheet.Range("A:L")
objRange.Copy
Set objExcel2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel2.Visible = False
objExcel2.DisplayAlerts = False
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel2.Workbooks.Open("<Target path>")
Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1")
objWorksheet2.Paste
objWorkbook2.Save
objWorkbook2.Close
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit  
objExcel2.Quit
```

Could you please help me how to suppress this alert and make my code works fine?

Comment: You're copying from Excel and pasting into Excel.  Why create two instances of Excel?  Open the workbooks in the same instance and the problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

The error/alert says that it can't paste the date as formulas but only as values.

Why don't you change the code to Paste as Values in the first place? You can do that using `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.

Or within your code:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("<Source path>")
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set objRange = objWorksheet.Range("A:L")
objRange.Copy
Set objExcel2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel2.Visible = False
objExcel2.DisplayAlerts = False
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel2.Workbooks.Open("<Target path>")
Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1")
objWorksheet2.Range("A:L").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
objWorkbook2.Save
objWorkbook2.Close
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit  
objExcel2.Quit
```

Comment: In this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/68625712/5518385 someone experienced the same issue when copying over two Excel instances. You can try the solution there

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, i have gone through it and prepared similar script but getting error like 'arr.vbs(1, 14) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using two instances of Excel.  If this is just purely Excel (not sure what the Informatica tool is) then this code should work:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim TargetBook As Workbook
    Set TargetBook = Workbooks.Open("<Target Path>")
    
    Dim SourceBook As Workbook
    Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open("<Source Path>")
    
    SourceBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:L").Copy Destination:=TargetBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
    
End Sub
```